# How to show confirmation message before opening the default messaging application?

Tags: android, sms

I want user to confirm By selecting yes or no that whether he/she is sure to open the message application or not.

This will be similar to `CALL CONFIRM` android app which confirms when making a call.

I can also manage if someone let me know a thing like broadcast receiver as in the case of making a call.
Like i would be able to confirm when send button is pressed in message application.
This is my first question on this forum. :)

Answer (score 1):

it can be achieved in more than one way,

1. create a service and monitor activity stack, if activity matches com.android.mms.* you can show your notification to user
2. create an application with all the intents for launching the messaging application, you can find out all possible intents from stock messaging application's android manifest file for your ref

http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/packages/apps/Mms/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks for answering sir,   I am new to android ,can you please elaborate or provide me a piece of code. Thanks in advance.